# Вывести знак % в счетчике через js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как можно вывести знак % в счетчике через код?

```js
$('.count').each(function () {
        $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
        duration: 5000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="count">200</span>
```

Comment: А где именно должен находиться % ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('.count').each(function() {
  $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
    Counter: $(this).text()
  }, {
    duration: 5000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function(now) {
      $(this).text(Math.ceil(now) + '%');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="count">300</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Как можно вывести знак % в счетчике через код?

Предложу такой вариант - JS + CSS.

```js
$('.count').each(function () {
        $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
        duration: 5000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
    });
}).addClass('on');
```

```css
.count.on:after {
  content: '%';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="count">200</span>
```